# Accessing a folder containing .wav files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access a folder containing 50 .wav file samples (that I will use for my Gender Voice Classification (using PCA) project), but I cant seem to be able to access the folder properly.
The folder is unzipped of course.

the folder containing the file samples is named "SoundSamples", that is inside another folder named "soundFile" that is located on the desktop.

I am running the code below:

```
import os

raw_folder = '//Desktop//soundFile//SoundSamples//'
for file in os.listdir(raw_folder):
    print(file)
    filepath = os.path.join(raw_folder, file)
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
```

The output I get is an error saying "no such file or directory: '//Desktop//soundFile//SoundSamples//' "

Comment: Have you tried using the full path? C:/Users/yourUser/Desktop/soundFile/SoundSamples

Comment: `'//Desktop//soundFile//SoundSamples//'`  is not a valid path.

Comment: Consider: `os.path.abspath("Desktop") != os.path.abspath("//Desktop")`.

Comment: The folder in `os.listdir()` should either be an absolute path or a relative (sub)folder from your current working directory. Also forward slashes don't need to be escaped.  You're probably looking for `C:/Users/yourusername/Desktop/soundFile/SoundSamples` (replace yourusername with your actual username, obviously).

Comment: You nee the whole directroy and if you are usign os you can just use fsenconde something like 
deirectory= os.fsencode(r"C:\Users\YourUsernmae\Desktop\soundFile\SoundSamples)

Comment: Doubling up *forward* slashes is not necessary, but on my OS (MacOS X) it is not an error -- YMMV. Other than that **if this path exists**, there is no error in that code.

Comment: I have now changed the path to "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\soundFile\SoundSamples but still get the error. I am using a mac btw. If my mac is in another language, do I have to change the language aswell?

Comment: Your Mac doesn't have a C drive so that is kind of pointless. You also need to double up *backslashes* (if you want to use them, which is not needed on a Mac). Don't try random things, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the *relative* path to your Desktop folder by starting with the *absolute* path `/Desktop/..`. As a regular user, your desktop folder is stored somewhere deeper -- typically, something like `/Users/(yourname)/Desktop`. But don't hardcode that, Python can find the home folder for you!

```
import os
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser("~")
print home
raw_folder = home+'/Desktop/soundFile/SoundSamples'
for file in os.listdir(raw_folder):
    print(file)
```

The OS function [`expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) locates your home folder and returns it as a string. Then you can paste on whatever folder you are looking for -- `Desktop`, `Documents`, or any other path relative to your home.

Answer (score 0):

Your filepath should be:

Desktop/soundFile/SoundSamples

(You don't need double forward slashes)

Assuming that you're running it from your home directory, otherwise specify the full filepath:

/Users/your_username/Desktop/soundFile/SoundSamples

(where your_username is your username)

I'd also suggest using the `with open(file, 'r') as f:` method of reading or writing to files, as Python will automatically close it for you

```
import os

raw_folder = 'Desktop/soundFile/SoundSamples'
for file in os.listdir(raw_folder):
    print(file)
    filepath = os.path.join(raw_folder, file)
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```